# SQL to use query for different conditions

Tags: mysql, postgresql, liferay

```
SELECT statusid,COUNT(statusid),SUM(totalamount) 
FROM intrahrms_rems_reimbursement 
WHERE projectmanagerid='KA18041E'  GROUP BY statusid
```

This is my query and I am getting the results. But i want to use this query for businessunitid and accountsid.. 
I can write this query as

```
SELECT statusid,COUNT(statusid),SUM(totalamount) 
FROM intrahrms_rems_reimbursement 
WHERE businesunitid='KA18049E'  GROUP BY statusid
```

and same for accounts

```
SELECT statusid,COUNT(statusid),SUM(totalamount) 
FROM intrahrms_rems_reimbursement 
WHERE accountsid='KA18043E'  GROUP BY statusid
```

So how can i write this query that can perform according to either Project Manager or Business Unit or Accounts

Comment: What's the intention?

Comment: I am not clear - do you want to reuse the query for Project Manager or Business Unit or Accounts or do you want 1 query which looks at all of Project Manager or Business Unit or Accounts?

Comment: yes, I want that my 1 query can perform same  functionality for PM BU and accounts

Answer (score 2):

I think `OR` clause is what you're looking for.

```
SELECT 
  statusid, 
  COUNT(statusid), 
  SUM(totalamount) 
FROM 
  intrahrms_rems_reimbursement 
WHERE 
  projectmanagerid = 'KA18041E' 
  OR businesunitid = 'KA18049E' 
  OR accountsid = 'KA18043E' 
GROUP BY 
  statusid
```